# dangerouslySetInnerHTML showing object on mapped data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, wp-graphql

I tried getting some values from an GraphQL data. Then, I want to display it via 
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ExtendedProfileShow }} />`

Then, I got `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`.

Here are my codes:

The error File:

```
export default function Profile({ profileData }) {
    const ExtendedProfileShow = [
        profileData.businessInfo.extendedProfile.map((showExtendedProfile) => (
            <div key={showExtendedProfile.title}>
                {showExtendedProfile.title} <br/> {showExtendedProfile.info}    
            </div>
        ))
    ]

    return (
        <> 
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ExtendedProfileShow }} />
        </>
    );
}
```

My api.js:

```
export async function getAllBusinessProfiles() {
    const data = await fetchAPI(
      `
      query AllProfiles {
        businessProfiles(where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: ASC}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              date
              title
              slug
              link
              uri
              businessInfo {
                name
                title
                company
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                  altText
                }
                highlight
                phone
                city
                country
                facebook
                linkedin
                instagram
                email
                website
                profiles {
                  profile
                  profileInfo
                }
                extendedProfile {
                  title
                  info
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
      `
    );
    return data?.businessProfiles;
};
```

The data has HTML elements like - `<p> Test test </p>` And it's expected to execute the tags also.

What could be error here? Thanks.

Comment: can you try <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ExtendedProfileShow.join('') }} />

Comment: Still shows `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: The `__html` prop expects a string.

Comment: How can I pass that? Help

Answer (score 2):

In this case there's no need to even use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You can simply pass the JSX you generate directly.

```js
export default function Profile({ profileData }) {
    const ExtendedProfileShow = [
        profileData.businessInfo.extendedProfile.map((showExtendedProfile) => (
            <div key={showExtendedProfile.title}>
                {showExtendedProfile.title} <br/> {showExtendedProfile.info}    
            </div>
        ))
    ]

    return (
        <> 
            <div>{ExtendedProfileShow}</div>
        </>
    );
}
```

However, if for some reason you really wanted to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you could use [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) to convert your JSX to a string.

```js
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

export default function Profile({ profileData }) {
    const ExtendedProfileShow = [
        profileData.businessInfo.extendedProfile.map((showExtendedProfile) => (
            <div key={showExtendedProfile.title}>
                {showExtendedProfile.title} <br/> {showExtendedProfile.info}    
            </div>
        ))
    ]

    return (
        <> 
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(ExtendedProfileShow)
            }} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: It tried this. And I got something like this: <br/> `<h2><span style="color: #ff6600;">Test here</span></h2> `
I actually want it not to show the HTML tags but execute all

Comment: Both returns the same output. `<h2><span style="color: #ff6600;">Test here</span></h2>`

Comment: Are you converting the JSX inside the array to a string by any chance? Or is you code exactly the same as my examples? You're not using `ExtendedProfileShow.join('')`, are you?

Comment: Yes, the same as your example. I didn't change any

Comment: Still the same, sir.

Comment: My guess is that those HTML tags come as string somehow, so it's rendering them as such. Is the full JSX in the array being rendered as a string, or only part of it? If you could provide a reproducible example (with the data you are using) that would be helpful